# SQL SSIS Closing Files already in use

Tags: sql-server, ssis, etl, hardware

Sometimes when running SSIS packages on flat files, I receive error: "The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process".

Another person already has file opened.

Is there a way for SSIS to manually close the file, so it can be processed?
I assume SSIS needs admin rights in the folder its processing.
I don't see "Close file" option in FileSystem task? Should I maybe use Powershell?

Please let me know of best options, I prefer SSIS first.

Thanks,

Comment: I have nothing constructive to add, I just think it's funny that there's not a NOLOCK hint for the file system.

Comment: Can you copy+ rename the file to a “temporary” location? That way your copy is never open... would that work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it's not safe to unlock a file used by another process, if it's used by another process it's likely writing to the file.  If you unlock the file it will likely corrupt the data.
to perform this action You may first kill the process who use the file.

as a Reference Checkout a Task Manger wrote in C#

https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/49983/Task-Manager

but you should consider that when you try to close the handle! The Other Process is going to crash. And if that process was writing to the file (which is said it was going to do by opening the file in that way) when you close the file handle, there is a risk that the file will now be corrupt.actually the safest way to perform this as @Dan says would be using a Stage Location

Stage Location: "it's more like a Rule with any user or application instead of Opening the file directly should make a copy of the file some where and finally Merge its changes to the file whenever done working with the file. There's no clear way of doing this unless you implement a a Queue Mechanism to access the file which you should implement a mid layer between your applications and your file"

Comment: it's more like a Rule with any user or application instead of Opening the file directly should make a copy of the file some where and finally Merge its changes to the file whenever done working with the file.
There's no clear way of doing this unless you implement a a Queue Mechanism to access the file which you should implement a mid layer between your applications and your file

Answer (score 0):

When an application opens a file, it specifies what type of access is allowed by concurrent processes (none, read, read/write, etc.). SSIS cannot change that. The file must either be closed or the other process terminated.

Although you could programmatically identify the terminate local processes owning a file handle, that can be challenging with remote processes and/or UNC paths. Personally, I wouldn't go there. A better solution is to have users copy files to a staging location once they are ready and have the ETL process them up from there.

Comment: what is a stage location for files? Is it like a staging database? do you have a url link describing it maybe? thanks

Comment: I'm suggesting a staging folder drop location with permissions for both end users and the ETL process. The folder/share could be located on the same box as the ETL, or on a remote file server, which would be accessed via UNC path. Users should copy files to the drop location and never open files directly from there to avoid the open file problem.

Comment: yeah, we already did something like that a 'stage folder', people were opening them anyway, I will try find another windows folder permission, copy/move but cannot read